# Product of two regular varieties over an imperfect field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to find a counterexample to the following, but am unable to find one. Any help would be appreciated, and also an explanation of why it works.

I am trying to show that over an imperfect field k, the fiber product of two regular varieties can fail to be regular. For an algebraically closed field, every product of regular varieties is regular, but the same shouldn't hold for imperfect.

Comment: If you can show that there exists $\mathrm{K}_1$ and $\mathrm{K}_2$ two finite separable extensions of an imperfect field $k$, such that $\mathrm{K}_1 \otimes_k \mathrm{K}_2$ is not separable, then you have an example.

Comment: Think of a polynomial over $k=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ that satisfies the Jacobian criterion and hence is regular, but upon base change to $k^{1/p}$ the equation factors to have repeated roots and hence is not reduced. Then $Spec(k[x]/(f))$ will be an example where $f$ is that equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $k$ is imperfect, say of characteristic $p$, there exists $\alpha\in k$ which is not a $p$-th power in $k$. Consider $K=k[X]/(X^p-\alpha)$. This is a field, finite over $k$, so it defines a regular variety $V$.

Now consider the fiber product $V\times_k V$. Its ring of regular functions is $$K\otimes_k K=K\otimes_k k[X]/(X^p-\alpha)=K[X]/(X^p-\alpha)=K[X]/(X-\theta)^p $$ 
where $\theta\in K$ is the class of $X$ in $K$. This shows that $V\times_k V$ not regular, it is not even reduced !